# How to add timer in speech input in python?

Tags: python, input, timer, voice-recognition

**I want to add the timer for the 10sec audio input**

```
    import speech_recognition as 

r= Recognizer()

with Microphone() as source:
    while(i==0):
        print('Say Something')
        audio = r.listen(source)
        query = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print(query)
```

Comment: This seems unclear. Are you saying you want to add a 10 second delay between each `r.listen`? Do you want `r.listen` to time out after 10 seconds? Do you want to add a timer display that counts down 10 seconds?

Comment: I want to read a string only for 10 sec each time

Comment: Why not use `listen()`'s `timeout` parameter? Documentation here: https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst#recognizer_instancelistensource-audiosource-timeout-unionfloat-none--none-phrase_time_limit-unionfloat-none--none-snowboy_configuration-uniontuplestr-iterablestr-none--none---audiodata